# Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: android

I am running Appium via Eclipse, to run my tests. Getting error. Pls suggest.

below is the error

> Unhandled error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\gnagaraj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\gnagaraj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\build-tools'

Answer (score 0):

Add the above path in your system environment PATH variable

> C:\Users\gnagaraj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\gnagaraj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\build-tools